# How do I measure text size in COSMIC-Text?

Tags: rust

Any Idea how to measure text size in COSMIC-Text?

My idea didn't work:

```rust
pub fn measure_text(text: &str,
                    attrs: Attrs, buffer: &mut Buffer) -> Option<Size> {
    buffer.set_text(&mut font_system(), text, attrs, Shaping::Advanced);
    buffer.shape_until_scroll(&mut font_system());

    // Get the layout runs
    let layout_runs: LayoutRunIter = buffer.layout_runs();
    let mut run_width: f32 = 0.;
    let mut run_height_low: f32 = f32::max_value();
    let mut run_height_high: f32 = f32::min_value();
    let mut w: u32 = 0;
    println!("======== {} ===========", text);
    for run in layout_runs {
        // Take the max. width of all lines.
        run_width = run_width.max(run.line_w);
        // Take the total height of all lines together.
        run_height_high = run_height_high.max(run.line_y);
        run_height_low = run_height_low.min(run.line_top);

        for g in run.glyphs {
            let mut tmp = swash_cache();
            let img = tmp.get_image(&mut font_system(), g.physical((0., 0.), 1.).cache_key);
            w += &img.clone().unwrap().placement.width;
        }
        // Tested with text without wrapping, so the main loop is run only once.
    }
    println!("w: {}, run_width: {}", w, run_width);
    Size::from_wh(w as f32, run_height_high - run_height_low)
}
```

But this doesn't work, neither `w` nor `run_width` are big enough, at the end of the function (although the height is perfect). They get bigger as the text gets longer, but they are still smaller than the actual text. So I can't center the text.

What do I do? How do I measure the *actual* text size?

Comment: Not sure why `line_w` is not large enough (its documentation is not clear, I don't know the crate at all) but the issue with `w` makes sense to me: you're summing the widths of the glyphs, but not taking in account the spacing between them. Maybe instead of iterating the glyphs you could try to take the width *and horizontal offset* of the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Almost finishing the conversion from GTK to self-drawn with COSMIC-Text, I could finally test a working solution in an actual, complicated application.

While this should work with multi-line text, I got only satisfying results with oneliners.

```rust
/**
Measures text.

Calls `set_text(...)` and `shape_until_scroll(...)` on the `buffer`.
Consider this, so either save the extra calls when exactly that text with that shaping instruction
should be used, or make the calls explicitly again, for other shapes and texts.

Don't forget to set the `buffer` size before calling this. Will panic if the `buffer` size isn't
set.
 */
pub fn measure_text(text: &str,
                    attrs: Attrs, buffer: Rc<RefCell<Buffer>>) -> Option<Size> {
    assert!(buffer.borrow().size().0 > 0.);
    assert!(buffer.borrow().size().1 > 0.);

    buffer.borrow_mut().set_text(&mut font_system(), text, attrs, Shaping::Advanced);
    buffer.borrow_mut().shape_until_scroll(&mut font_system());

    // Get the layout runs
    let buffer_borrowed = buffer.borrow();
    let layout_runs: LayoutRunIter = buffer_borrowed.layout_runs();
    let mut run_width: f32 = 0.;
    let line_height = buffer_borrowed.lines.len() as f32 * buffer_borrowed.metrics().line_height;
    for run in layout_runs {
        // Take the max. width of all lines.
        run_width = run_width.max(run.line_w);
    }
    Size::from_wh(run_width.ceil(), line_height)
}
```